# Default Installation Path for Chromium Web Browser in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, chromium

I am a newbie both to Ubuntu and Linux and the Chromium web browser.  Try as I might, I have been unsuccessful in finding the answer to this simple question:  What is the default installation path for the Chromium web browser in Ubuntu 16.04?

Thanks in advance for answering this relatively simple question!

Answer (score 19):

You can type:

```
which chromium-browser
```

in a terminal to find out.

Mine is in `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` and yours probably is too.

Comment: Didn't work for me after `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. It seems to have been installed somewhere that is not on my `$PATH`

Comment: I keep forgetting, on zsh I need to execute `rehash` for the index of $PATH contents to be refreshed.

Comment: @Scott Shipp: console show: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser' but when I use 'cd /usr/bin/chromium-browser' it display '-bash: cd: /usr/bin/chromium-browser: Not a directory'

Comment: if Chromium was installed with Snap, it works with `which chromium`

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but I found it looking for Chromium in 18.10.

Please note that Chromium may have been installed utilizing Snap, in which case it is likely in `/snap/chromium/current/bin/chromium.desktop`

I am new to snap, so it took me a little time to realize this.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you mean by installation path but the following `dpkg` command might help:

```
dpkg -L chromium-browser
```

as it will show all the files associated with the installed package.

Comment: In other words there is no single path, the programs resources are stored in different places following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find directory of your program just use this in console (like example):

```
whereis chromium
```

and then you see like this:

```
chromium: /snap/bin/chromium /snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
which chromium
```

My default installation is

```
/snap/bin/chromium
```

This is for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to refresh your `$PATH` contents index after executing `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. Here is how you do it for each shell:

### Bash

```
hash -r
```

### Zsh

```
rehash
```

Then you should find that `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` gets found with `which chromium-browser` as well as just executing `chromium-browser` without any directory prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I used `whereis chromium` and got this output

```
chromium: /etc/chromium
```

In my case, Chromium was installed via npm.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the binary file or the empty string.

```
type -p chromium-browser
```